# Magento 1.9.1 sent unsolicited bulk new order notifications

Tags: php, magento, notifications, magento-1.9

Yesterday all my customers received a new order notification for their past orders in my shop using Magento 1.9.1. Even completed orders have been notified.
I am worried that my site was hacked but I can't find any trace of the request that sent this mails.

Does anyone have any idea how this happened?

Comment: Is you site fully patched with all magento patches? Was there any developer working on your site when the incident happened?

Comment: There's no developer working at all. Magento wasn't updated to version 1.9.2 yet.

Comment: did you recently make changes to your cron scheduler?  From 1.9 cron plays a very important role in email comms.

Comment: Nope: */15 * * * * php /home/...../cron.php > /dev/null

Comment: Luis, my guess is that the table core_email_queue had a decent amount of transactional emails stored.. Whether be accident or on purpose they were sent.  Additionally, the server should have a mail.log that you can view. Try creating an order and see if that table has your email in it.  Check again after the next cron ..  Which is 15 mins in your case and see if it's still in there.